синхронизация позиции дочерних элементов photon unity
Есть два игрока, движение которых должно синхронизироваться с помощью PhotonTransformViewClassic. Это работает, но если сделать игроков дочерними другому объекту, синхронизация пропадает. (на этот объект так же добавлен PhotonTransformViewClassic. В чем причина?
